# CoreData property set to nil when entity is fault

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data

Is there a way to set a CoreData property which was deleted, automatically to nil and not to a (DELETED) fault (which the app cannot recover)

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) SomeCoreDataEntity * entity;

@end
```

**self.entity should be nil, when entity was deleted from persistent store**

Comment: What is the deletion rule you set for the relationship? how are you deleting the entity (from the same context)?

Comment: its not a relationship, the class (SomeClass) isn't a CoreData class